# Как вызвать функцию c параметрами через onclick js

Tags: javascript

Есть большая функция:

```js
function buy(name1, name2, cost, profit, buy, where1, where2, img) {
    if((name1+name2)/3 < 6){
        if(g2 == false){
            if(money2 >= cost){
                money2 = money2 - cost;
                shop2 = shop2 + profit;
                alert("Игрок 2 приобрел " + buy);
                moneygame2.innerHTML = money2;
                // кол-во шт.
                document.querySelector(where2).innerHTML = shop2/profit;
                // вставить карточку
                if(shop2 <= profit){ 
                    document.querySelector('#gamer2').innerHTML += img;
                    document.querySelector(where2).style.left = left2 + 'px';
                    left2 += 140;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(g1 == false){
            if(money1 >= cost){
                money1 = money1 - cost;
                shop1 = shop1 + profit;
                alert("Игрок 1 приобрел "+buy);
                moneygame1.innerHTML = money1;
                // кол-во шт.
                document.querySelector(where1).innerHTML = shop1/profit;
                // вставить карточку
                if(shop1 <= profit){
                    document.querySelector('#gamer1').innerHTML += img;
                    document.querySelector(where1).style.left = left1 + 'px';
                    left1 += 140;
                }
            }
        }
        hod();
    } else{
        alert('Карточки закончились!');
    }
}
```

Как ее вызвать через `onclik`?

```js
 document.querySelector('#shop').onclick = buy(shop1, shop2, '2', '3', "магазин", "#shopCol-vo1", "#shopCol-vo2", '<img class="img" src="images/МАГАЗИН.png">');
```

Так почему-то функция вызывается сразу(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас в коде `goodFunction()`, то это её вызов вне зависимости от контекста. Если у вас в коде `goodFunction`, то её скорее можно воспринимать как переменную.

Два варианта:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(){ myFunction(p1, p2); }); 
// or
element.onclick = function(){ myFunction(p1, p2); };
```

Answer (score 2):

Несколько демонстраций...

Когда onclick еще не определен:

```js
console.log( document.querySelector('#shop').onclick ); // null
```

```html
<button id="shop">shop</button>
```

После определения:

```js
document.querySelector('#shop').onclick = function(x){
  alert( x = 0 );
  return x;
}

console.log( document.querySelector('#shop').onclick ); 
// выводит всю функцию, которая будет вызываться при клике
```

```html
<button id="shop">shop</button>
```

Поставив скобки после функции - вызываете её сразу, а в консоли выводится null, будто её и не было:

```js
document.querySelector('#shop').onclick = (function(x){
  alert( x = 0 );
  return x;
})(); // добавлены скобки, срабатывает сразу

console.log( document.querySelector('#shop').onclick ); // null
```

```html
<button id="shop">shop</button>
```

Получится та же история, если дать название функции и использовать её вместо самой функции (вся функция как-бы сохранена в переменную bubu):

```js
function bubu(x){
  alert( x = 0 );
  return x;
}

document.querySelector('#shop').onclick = (bubu)(); // или просто bubu(); Сработает сразу

console.log( document.querySelector('#shop').onclick ); // null

document.querySelector('#demo').onclick = bubu; // Без скобок, по прежнему является функцией

console.log( document.querySelector('#demo').onclick ); // Которая сработает при клике
```

```html
<button id="shop">shop</button>
<button id="demo">demo</button>
```

Но скобки необходимы, чтобы указать параметры... тогда придется обернуть вызов функции с параметрами - в дополнительную функцию, которая не будет вызываться сразу:

```
onclick = function(){ bubu(a, b, c, d); }
```

P.s. (не относится к вопросу)

Но вообще говоря, если у функции дофига параметров, удобнее с ними работать в виде объекта, так (после `||` указаны значения по дефолту, если при вызове они не будут получены):

```js
function bubu( obj ){
  console.log( obj.name || "Вася" );
  console.log( obj.img  || "Ссылка не получена" );
  console.log( obj.cost || 100500 );  
  console.log( obj.bubu || "bubu" );
}

var x = {
  name: 'Онотолей',
  cost: '5000 руб',
  bubu: 'Просто Бубу'
}

bubu(x);
```